# Xcode Text View Specific Attributes iOS + Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextview

I have a text view in Xcode and I want certain lines in the text view to be aligned in the center and other lines to be aligned left within the text view. Picture:[image]

I want "HOW UV RADIATION WORKS?" to be aligned in the center and "UV Rays Cause:" to be aligned left.

Comment: I don't see a question here. Can you clearly state what you want help with? Do you want the text box to moved, or do you want the text alignment within the box changed? It's not entirely clear what you're asking.

Comment: I want the text alignment within the text box changed.

Answer (score 0):

In the Interface Builder, select the text you want to change the alignment of. Open the Utilities pane. Click on the Attributes inspector (the one that looks like a little slider control). You should see the Alignment field. Click on the icon for the alignment you want. It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: This applies to the whole text view, I want to apply a different alignment for each line of text.

Comment: You probably need to clarify your question, then. It's not at all clear that there are multiple lines of text in a single text view. Is there a reason you're using only a single text view instead of 2?

Comment: There is no specific reason, I just wanted the layout to be cleaner with less text boxes.